# Chinese literature database 中文文学作品资料库

Tags: literature, database

Suppose I have a phrase like 说得很好, and I want to know how this phrase is normally used (that is, what usually comes before or after, e.g. maybe it's most commonly used in conjunction with the phrase 说英文).

Books, or even better, TV or movie scripts, would be the best place to search. In English, Google books would be what I would search.

Is there anything equivalent to a Google books search in Chinese? Is there any large database of books and TV/movie scripts that I could search?

谢谢！

Edit: while it's true that dictionaries provide this service to some extent, in many cases I find the amount of material too small. Considering this, please limit answers to *databases of literature* or ways to search them.

Comment: Have you tried verbatim search on baidu?

Comment: enter (sections of) text in online dictionaries, e.g. iciba, bkrs, results for 说得很好:iciba: 她英语说得很好,bkrs:他说汉语说得很好，我以为他早就去中国了

Comment: What's bkrs, iciba mean?

Comment: means dictionaries, search web

Comment: There's [ctext.org](http://ctext.org) for classic texts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [database of the Center for Chinese Linguistics PKU](http://ccl.pku.edu.cn:8080/ccl_corpus/index.jsp)

It supports modern and ancient Chinese, context-view.

Pattern search examples:

```
    爱(V,=2)不(V) will get 爱执行不执行, 2 characters following 爱, then 不 and max 10(default) characters.
    
    爱(V,2-5)不(V), 2 to 5 characters following 爱,
    
    爱(V,<5)不(V)
    
    有(V,<8)没(V,>7) wrong, only support 1 condition
```

It has many other features, described in the [documentation](http://ccl.pku.edu.cn:8080/ccl_corpus/CCLCorpus_Readme.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%E8%AF%B4%E5%BE%97%E5%BE%88%E5%A5%BD) works with Chinese.

[91dict](http://www.91dict.com/) is a dictionary started by YYETS subtitle group. If you search your [说得很好](http://www.91dict.com/words?w=%E8%AF%B4%E5%BE%97%E5%BE%88%E5%A5%BD) and then click the "场景例句" you can see how it is used in sentences. The only snag is that usually the original language was English and these are translated subtitle sentences that you are getting.